# Alert for percentage increase of another alert?

Tags: pine-script

I'm using this simple EMA:

```
study(title="EMA 5/10/20", overlay=true)    
shortest = ema(close, 5)    
short = ema(close, 10)    
longer = ema(close, 20)    
plot(shortest, color = yellow, linewidth=2)    
plot(short, color = red, linewidth=2)    
plot(longer, color = purple, linewidth=2)    
EmaOpen = ta.crossover(shortest, longer)    
alertcondition(EmaOpen, title="EmaOpen", message= "Ema Open")
```

Which alerts me when the 5 EMA price cross over 20 EMA.

Is it possible to add another alert that can trigger when the price is above the (EmaOpen) alert by let's say 3%? So we can create some kind of a take profit signal if we bought at the EmaOpen signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EmaOpen will be `true` whenever there is a crossover. You should store the `close` price whenever that happens and calculate your 3% over that price. Then check if price crossesover your calculated value.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="EMA 5/10/20", overlay=true)

tp_per = input.float(3.0, "Take Profit %") / 100.0

shortest = ta.ema(close, 5)    
short = ta.ema(close, 10)    
longer = ta.ema(close, 20)    

var float EmaTp = na
EmaOpen = ta.crossover(shortest, longer)
EmaTp := EmaOpen ? close * (1 + tp_per) : EmaTp
tpBreached = ta.crossover(close, EmaTp)
EmaTp := tpBreached ? na : EmaTp

plot(shortest, color = color.yellow, linewidth=2)    
plot(short, color = color.red, linewidth=2)    
plot(longer, color = color.purple, linewidth=2)
plotshape(EmaOpen, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small)
plot(EmaTp, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles)
plotshape(tpBreached, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.green, size=size.small)

alertcondition(EmaOpen, title="EmaOpen", message= "Ema Open")
alertcondition(tpBreached, title="TP", message= "Take Profit")
```

- Blue "X"s are where the EMA cross takes place
- Green dots are your take profit level
- Green triangles are where the price hits your take profit level

[image]

Comment: vitruvius - Hello friend. I just wanted to thank you for your kind help there. I'm currently testing the codes. They're looking pretty good and will let you know if I found anything

Comment: No problem. You can accept my answer if it is working after you test.